# IdentityServer4 app architecture

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver4

I currently have the ability to host one and only one site (meaning under one domain). I will have a SPA front-end, Web Api resource, and then IdentityServer4 for security (utilizing AspNetCore Identity framework for user management).

Something feels "wrong" with this approach as a single hosted site architecture. I believe AspNet Identity creates an auth cookie once authenticated, and then IdentityServer would be serving up JWT tokens for my SPA to call my API.

Upon further reflection though, this seems misguided. The thing that seems off is that I believe my API calls will *also* have the auth cookie automatically attached along with the JWT token in the header because the API call will be requesting from the same domain as the auth cookie was generated. And so it seems I'm using two forms of authentication at once unnecessarily... thoughts?

In other words, when everything is running under one domain, is adding IdentityServer4 to an AspNetCore Identity-enabled application unnecessary?  The one benefit to plumbing in IdentityServer4 would be to future proof the application if it were to ever be deployed separate from its Resource (Web Api), then you would have nothing but configuration to modify.